# Accessing nested lists/dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am extracting data from ebay using ebay-sdkpython. The end goal is to have a XLS dump of items with specific fields for each item. The output that I want to manipulate comes as a complex nested list/dict as below:

```
dict = {'ack': 'Success', 
'timestamp': '2015-11-20T03:49:08.302Z', 
'version': '1.13.0', 
'searchResult': 
    {'item': [
        {'itemId': '111827613927', 
        'topRatedListing': 'false', 
        'sellingStatus': 
            {'currentPrice': 
                {'_currencyId': 'AUD', 
                'value': '290.0'}, 
            'convertedCurrentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'AUD', 'value': '290.0'}, 
            'sellingState': 'EndedWithSales'}, 
        'listingInfo': 
            {'listingType': 'FixedPrice', 
            'endTime': '2015-11-20T03:35:07.000Z'}
        }, 
    '_count': '100'}, 
'paginationOutput': 
    {'totalPages': '114', 
    'entriesPerPage': '100', 
    'pageNumber': '1', 
    'totalEntries': '11364'}}
```

I know that I can pull a specific key out using the following format:

```
print dict['searchResult']['item'][0]['itemId']
```

But I want to pull all of them, with the varying levels of nesting. I also need error handling as some fields are missing, these should return a ''. My code so far is:

```
    x=1
    for item in response.dict()['searchResult']['item']:
        print x,
        for field in ['itemId','topRatedListing']:
            try:
                print item[field]
            except KeyError:
                print ''

        x=x+1
        print '\n'
```

How would I modify this for loop to also include, for example, ['sellingstatus']['currentprice']['value'] ?

Comment: `value = item['sellingstatus']['currentprice']['value']`

Comment: you want to pull all 'items' or what you want to do exactly with the information? just print it? retrieve it to a list?

Comment: At this stage just print. Can the nested key i.e. ['sellingstatus']['currentprice']['value'] somehow be added into the same loop with keys on the higher tree level i.e. ['itemId','topRatedListing']? Sorry if my terminology is bad.